# Sequence error in AlertDialogs

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I would like to send a blocking message containing my contents. I tried the AlertDialog feature. The problem is that the message "good bye" appears before the "hello" one. There should be a simpler solution than mine. Any ideas?

```
package com.example.a00;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
//import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final int VISIBLE = 0;
    private static final int INVISIBLE = 4;
    private static final int GONE = 8;
    private String logval = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnAlert = new Button(this);
        //btnAlert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAlert);
        btnAlert.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAlert.setVisibility(GONE);  // VISIBLE, INVISIBLE or GONE
        //
        logval = "hello";
        btnAlert.performClick();   // should be displayed first
        //
            // continue processing
            //
        logval = "good bye";        // should be displayed last 
        btnAlert.performClick();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog1.setTitle("Titre");
        //alertDialog1.setMessage("message");
        alertDialog1.setMessage(logval);
        alertDialog1.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Toast ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog1.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens is that first `hello` dialog is opened and then on top of it `good bye` open. So eventually user sees ``Good Bye`dialog on the very top and then after it is closed, then the user sees the`hello` dialog which was opened first.

**Way 1:**

One simple option is that open the first dialog of `hello`. Then inside `onClick` open another dialog of `good bye`. What this would do is that only when user clicks on `ok` or any other button on first dialog, then only second dialog of `good bye` would open. So in short try to open one dialog box from with in `onClick` of another. See [Android display another dialog from a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662538/android-display-another-dialog-from-a-dialog) and  [alert dialog after another alert dialog ? The first is missing! android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501357/alert-dialog-after-another-alert-dialog-the-first-is-missing-android)

**Way 2:** Another is to Simply reverse the position of both of them:

```
logval = "good bye";
btnAlert.performClick();  
....
logval = "hello";
btnAlert.performClick();
```

So the `Good bye` would open first but immidiately `hello` would open on top of it. 
hope this helps.